# String Index out of bounds exception when using blank space

Tags: java, arraylist, char, runtime-error

I'm making a chatbot, and it needs to break down every sentence into an array list of strings. It gives me a string index out of bounds exception whenever I use a space. I honestly don't know what to do about this, I've looked all over the forums, please help.

```
char tempChar;
String tempLetter;
String tempString = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++) {
    Scanner breakDownScan = new Scanner(input);
    tempChar = breakDownScan.next().charAt(i-1);

    if (tempChar != ' ' && tempChar != '.' && tempChar != '!' && tempChar != '?') {
        tempLetter = Character.toString(tempChar);
        tempString += tempLetter;
    }

    if (tempChar == ' ' || tempChar == '.' || tempChar == '!' || tempChar == '?') {
        System.out.println("test");
        words.add(tempString);
    }

    if (i == input.length()) {
        breakDownScan.close();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advanced for any and all help you can provide :D

Comment: Is your input 1 sentence? or a stream of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the split method. Example:

```
String[] words = input.split(insert your desired parser here);
```

I do believe you can do just the same with an Array List :)
(for the parser, use a space(" "), or what ever your words are separated by)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that is exactly what I needed :D By the way, if this is a question that has already been answered, I'm very sorry, I searched for it, and didn't find something matching my issue, but if it has already been answered, it would be great if a mod could take it down.